# why is concrete object being set to null in controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, authorize.net

When I send a request to my controller, for some reason it assigns all null values to the object:

[image]

The request I am sending is as follows:

```
    {
  "createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest": {
      "merchantAuthentication": {
    "name": "3efsw3sd66",
    "transactionKey": "7m444433G"
  },
    "customerProfileId": "10000",
    "paymentProfile": {
      "billTo": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": "123 Main St.",
        "city": "Bellevue",
        "state": "WA",
        "zip": "98004",
        "country": "USA",
        "phoneNumber": "000-000-0000"
      },
      "payment": {
        "creditCard": {
          "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
          "expirationDate": "2023-12"
        }
      },
      "defaultPaymentProfile": false
    },
    "validationMode": "liveMode"
  }
}
```

This is how I issue the request from postman:

[image]

**Why are the properties of my request being set to null?**

The class is defined as:

```
 /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest : ANetApiRequest {

    /// <remarks/>
    public string customerProfileId;

    /// <remarks/>
    public customerPaymentProfileType paymentProfile;

    /// <remarks/>
    public validationModeEnum validationMode;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool validationModeSpecified;
}
```

Its parent is defined as:

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd")]
public partial class ANetApiRequest {

    /// <remarks/>
    public merchantAuthenticationType merchantAuthentication;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string clientId;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string refId;
}
```

And one of the properties is defined as:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd")]
public partial class merchantAuthenticationType {

    /// <remarks/>
    public string name;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("accessToken", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("clientKey", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fingerPrint", typeof(fingerPrintType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("impersonationAuthentication", typeof(impersonationAuthenticationType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("password", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sessionToken", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("transactionKey", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string mobileDeviceId;
}
```

and another one:

```
    public partial class customerPaymentProfileType : customerPaymentProfileBaseType {

    /// <remarks/>
    public paymentType payment;

    /// <remarks/>
    public driversLicenseType driversLicense;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string taxId;

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool defaultPaymentProfile;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool defaultPaymentProfileSpecified;
}
```

Comment: Try using `[FromBody]` attribute and see if that fixes the problem. `Go([FromBody] ParameterType request)`

Comment: nope it did not https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OvsOhha2Q3k/WZJViRz1QOI/AAAAAAAADeM/qjZFl246FI4W-kvOxfRz55F3rFrjfEY8wCHMYCw/s0/devenv_2017-08-14_20-59-35.png

Comment: Show the class. need to be able to compare json to class it is mapping to

Comment: Ok i think I figured it out. You json has one level too deep which basically has `new { createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest = new {...}}` when you should have that property as the root

Comment: the json is straight from documentation https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-sBZKMpYgCwM/WZJWjDHCfNI/AAAAAAAADeU/TdA513eApkUa-zEROrZj32ZSbwqpzbknQCHMYCw/s0/chrome_2017-08-14_21-03-55.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json being sent is one level too deep.

The payload should be

```
  {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
      "name": "3efsw3sd66",
      "transactionKey": "7m444433G"
    },
    "customerProfileId": "10000",
    "paymentProfile": {
      "billTo": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": "123 Main St.",
        "city": "Bellevue",
        "state": "WA",
        "zip": "98004",
        "country": "USA",
        "phoneNumber": "000-000-0000"
      },
      "payment": {
        "creditCard": {
          "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
          "expirationDate": "2023-12"
        }
      },
      "defaultPaymentProfile": false
    },
    "validationMode": "liveMode"
  }
```

Otherwise in order to match the json you have there the model would have to look like this

```
public class Example {
    public createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest { get; set; }
}
```